# php variable in exec()

Tags: php, variables, exec

I'm trying to reuse the output of *$a* but I can't find the right way to write this line:
After a look in the previous thread some resolution didn't worked for me..

I tried:

$hs1=exec("$a | cut -c12-16");

$hs1=exec("$a | cut -c12-16");

$hs1=exec("($a | cut -c12-16)");

$hs1=exec('($a | cut -c12-16)');

and other combination, but nothing works...

```
$a=exec('sudo loldht 4 | tail -1');
...
$hs1=exec("$a | cut -c12-16)");
$ts1=exec('(sudo loldht 4 | tail -1 | cut -c34-39)');

echo $hs1 . " : " . $ts1;
```

Anyone could help me for that?
Thank you.

Comment: The user who execute your php script can sudo password less ?

Comment: Try to add an output variable as second parameter to exec to get all the output because exec return only the last line of the result

Comment: @MelvynMarigny, Yes , for $a & $ts1, I can echo the output. The command $a is quite long so instead of run it 2 times I want to reuse it to get $hs1 & $ts1.

Comment: What error do you have ?

Comment: @MelvynMarigny I didn't have any error but nothing displayed for the $hs1 variable.

Comment: Just saw that you have a closing parenthesis at the end in this case $hs1=exec("$a | cut -c12-16)");, try without : $hs1=exec("$a | cut -c12-16");  . If it 's not working, can you add the second parameter to exec() to get the complete output : $hs1=exec("$a | cut -c12-16", $output); and then print_r($output); ?

Comment: output is: PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/functions/read2.php on line 5

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Using another way, but still.

```
$a = "(sudo loldht 4 | tail -1";
$b = $a . " | cut -c12-16)";
$c = $a . " | cut -c34-39)";
$hs1=exec("$b");
$ts1=exec("$c");

echo $hs1 . " : " . $ts1
```

Thanks for your time @MelvynMarigny!